# Best practice to exit sub with functions

Tags: vb.net, winforms, function, return

I am looking for a way to write a function that will stop all code (exit sub) without me having to write an **If Statement** for the function in the sub routine.

For example:

```
Public Class Form_Main
    Private Sub Button_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Search.Click
        If CountNumbers() = False Then Exit Sub 
        ' Is there a way for me to write "CountNumbers" only and it will
        ' [Exit Sub] without me having to write an if statement?
        ' Sort of embedding the Exit Sub in the function?
    End Sub

    Function CountNumbers()
        Dim a As Integer = 1
        If a = 1 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: No there's not. Why do you want to do that anyway? What's wrong with an inline If statement?

Comment: What's wrong with "If statement"?

Comment: What would this achieve for you?  It would make the code unreadable, especially for the next programmer that doesn't know the code is exiting from that line.

Comment: If you are looking for Best Practices, start with Option Strict

Comment: Yes, just call CountNumbers(), as you're not doing anything with the result of CountNumbers the sub will exit anyway. if you never exit the click handler your application will just hang forever.

Comment: technically...you could throw a custom exception and then have a catch block to handle that...but why would you do that

Comment: My initial thought was throwing an exception but then it'd have to be caught and that's more code than the if statement!

Comment: Functions have a data type. `Function CountNumbers() As Boolean`

Comment: You can simplify your If a bit. `If  Not CountNumbers()  Then Return` CountNumbers() evaluates to a boolean so the = False is not necessary. Exit Sub is vb specific. Return is used in several languages.

Comment: With this example just call exit sub when the button is clicked...since you're not doing anything. Well just remove the event at this point...

Comment: Is the "best practice" in the title supposed to be ironic?

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Return` keyword with out supplying a value

```
Public Sub Foo()
    If Bar() = False Then
        Return
    End If
End Sub
```